# Non-object error on a certified object

Tags: php, object, symfony

I'm working on a Symfony form with non-entity fields (in a collection).

(EDIT: All the code below is now working well!)

### What we're talking about

For comprehension this is some code snippets :
Form definition (in PieceType class):

```
// Form\Type\PieceType.php

$builder
    ->add('name',
          'text',
          array('max_length' => 70,
                'label' => "piece.name"))
    ->add('compositors',
          'collection',
          array('type' => 'entity',
                'options' => array('class' => 'kalisonStdArchiveBundle:Person',
                                   'property_path' => false),
          'allow_add' => true,
          'allow_delete' => true,
          'property_path' => false,
          'by_reference' => false,
          'label' => 'piece.compositor'
    ));
```

The compositors fields are added using javascript, using the data-prototype (explained [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#adding-and-removing-items)).

The rendering is simply done using that view:

```
// Resources\views\Piece\piece.new.html.twig

{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}
<script type="text/javascript">var nbCompositors = {{ form.compositors|length }}</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/kalisonstdarchive/js/piece.new.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock javascripts %}

{% block main %}
<form novalidate action="{{ path("kalisonStdArchiveBundle_piece_new") }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <button id="add-compositor">{{ "compositor.add"|trans }}</button>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="{{ "piece.create"|trans }}" name="submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

The javascript associated is:

```
// Resources\public\js\piece.new.js

$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#add-compositor').click(function() {
        var list = jQuery('#kalison_stdarchivebundle_piecetype_compositors');
        var newCompositor = list.attr('data-prototype');
        newCompo = newCompositor.replace(/\$\$name\$\$/g, nbCompositors);
        nbCompositors++;
        var html = jQuery('<p></p>').html(newCompositor);
        html.appendTo(jQuery('#kalison_stdarchivebundle_piecetype_compositors'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

And here is the action which manage the datas. As notified by @l3l0, I wasn't checking last iteration, which causes a $addCompositor null:

```
// Controller\PieceController.php

$newPiece = new Piece();
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new PieceType(), $newPiece);

if ('POST' == $request->getMethod()) {
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) { 
        $this->get('piece_manager')->savePiece($newPiece);

        if ($form["compositors"] != null) { 
            foreach ($form["compositors"] as $formCompositor) {
                $addCompositor = $formCompositor->getData();
                if ($addCompositor != null) {
                    $newPerfomance = new Performance();
                    $newPerfomance->setPerson($addCompositor); // Throw Catchable Fatal Error
                    $newPerfomance->setPiece($newPiece);
                    $newPerfomance->setInstrument($instrument);
                    $this->get('performance_manager')->savePerformance($newPerfomance);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that I got a Symfony error telling that: `Argument 1 passed to Performance::setPerson() must be an instance of Person, null given`. (Of course, the method in Performance class is `public function setPerson(Person $person)`)

### What I've tried

- I tried to check for sure: `if (!is_object($addCompositor)) throw new Exception('NOT AN OBJECT');`

  And yes, `$addCompositor` is really an object.
- I assumed it was an incompatible object, but if try to print the object: `var_dump($addCompositor)`.

  I'm not surprised to get: `object(...\Entity\Person)`
- finally my last test was to call a method on this object: `echo $addCompositor->getLastName();`.

  Worked as well, printing the name - and just after throw this well known error: `Call to a member function getLastName() on a non-object`.

So, my code looks like that now:

```
foreach ($form["compositors"] as $formCompositor) {
    $addCompositor = $formCompositor->getData();
    if (!is_object($addCompositor))
        throw new Exception('NOT AN OBJECT'); // Not throwing: it's an object
    var_dump($addCompositor); // Print a Person object
    echo $addCompositor->getLastName(); // Print the name, then break on "non-object" error
    $newPerfomance = new Performance();
    $newPerfomance->setPerson($addCompositor); // Throw Catchable Fatal Error
    $newPerfomance->setPiece($newPiece);
    $newPerfomance->setInstrument($instrument);
    $this->get('performance_manager')->savePerformance($newPerfomance);
}
```

### Where is your god now?

At first I thought it was a Symfony bug, but with that last test I'm a bit confused.
Have you ever been facing that?

Comment: Check the lines where these errors are thrown, add the code of these lines.

Comment: I've add some explanations, is that enough? All the concerned code is here.

Comment: did you try to debug it with xdebug?

Comment: Uhm line numbers? File-names? Errors normally appear at specific positions, not that you look at the wrong objects / code.

Comment: @Inori, I try and I'll let you know.

Comment: Thanks @Inori, I didn't know that tool, know it's adopted!

Comment: @muxisar haha, you're welcome! It's indeed an awesome tool :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in next iterations you just not have data object.

Please check what data are submitted and show us JS code too. You can check what is in `$form["compositors"]` too

Ah can you tell which version of Symfony do you use? (2.0.x, 2.1 ?)

Comment: I've checked that `$form["compositors"]` is not empty, and when I print the name for example, I get the correct data. I'm using Symfony v2.0.15. I've added view and js in my first post.